# Cant update, driving me insane

Tags: updates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZT8Q.png)
Also have the issue were my resolvconf file gets overridden with the DNS servers I have set.
I have the nameservers set in netplan but doesn't seem to care.
Running Ubuntu 20.4 with unifi controller software on it.

Comment: First of all you appear to have a broken IPv6 setup. Either fix IPv6 or disable IPv6 address distribution / RA.